# how to change input field size with flask-admin

Tags: flask-admin

After studying long hours both the documentation and the source codes of flask-admin and wtforms, I still could not understand how to vary the size of input fields in flask-admin model forms.​

According to wtf "crash course" page, it should be possible to pass to the form fields css parameters in the templates, like this (jinja2 example):

```
<form method="POST" action="/login">
    <div>{{ form.username.label }}: {{ form.username(size="10") }}</div>
    <div>{{ form.password.label }}: {{ form.password() }}</div>
</form>
```

however, with Flask-Admin form fields / templates this does not seem possible. At least I have not found a decent way to do this

Any advice would be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're extending the `ModelView` class from `flask.ext.admin.contrib.sqla`, you can override the value of the template used. You can override either the list view of the model, the create view or the edit view, like so:

```
class CustomAdminView(ModelView):
    list_template = "list_template.html"
    edit_template = "edit_template.html"
    create_template = "create_template.html"
    ...
```

You'll need to create each of these templates yourself, and you can extend the default admin template to keep it consistent with all of the bespoke admin views. So, an example template would be:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .select2-container, .select2-container-active, #title, #author, #description {
        width: 75% !important;
    }
    .controls div input {
        height: 40px;
    }
    .select2-search-choice {
        width: 90%;
    }
    #visible {
        float: left;
        text-align: left;
    }
</style>
{% extends 'admin/model/edit.html' %}
```

Notice the last line: `{% extends 'admin/model/edit.html' %}`, which extends the default edit view from Flask Admin. You can change `edit` for `list` or `create` to extend those views instead.

Hope that clears things up.

Answer (score 12):

An option is to use `form_widget_args`, a dictionary with attributes for the model form fields,  in the model view.

For instance, to have 20 rows for a textarea for the 'description' field of a 'MyItem' model:

```py
class MyItemView(ModelView):
    form_widget_args = {
        'description': {
            'rows': 20
        }
    }
```

See http://flask-admin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/mod_model/

It is also possible to replace input fields entirely, by specifying `form_overrides`. E.g., to replace the textarea with a single-line input field:

```py
class MyItemView(ModelView):
    form_overrides = {
        'description': StringField,
    }
```

See http://flask-admin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced/ , 
http://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in this direction! I ended up adding a 'style' key to the `form_widget_args` dict, and it worked well. See [reference here](http://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mod_model/#flask_admin.model.BaseModelView.form_widget_args). i.e., `form_widget_args = {'my_field': {'style': 'width: 500px'}}`

Comment: form_overrides did it for me.

Comment: Of the two proposed, this solution is the simplest and most flexible.